# Navigation Drawer Activity классы ViewModel и Fragment

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Подскажите пожалуйста. Создала макет приложения по шаблону `"Navigation Drawer Activity"`. По умолчанию создались три фрагмента и на каждый фрагмент по два класса, например `HomeViewModel` и `HomeFragment`.

Во фрагмент добавила два `EditText` и один `Spinner`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtTranslit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Не могу понять для чего служат два класса `ViewModel` и `Fragment` для каждого фрагмента. Нельзя ли в одном классе всю логику описать? Например в Классе `HomeFragment` у меня такой код, а класс `HomeViewModel` пустой и не понимаю что в нем описывать.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        final EditText text = root.findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        text.setText(testMethod());

        return root;
    }

    private String testMethod() {
        return "Text";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что в классе ViewModel я могу получать данные из каких-то репозиториев, баз данных и писать методы для работы с этими данными. А в классе Fragment вызывать эти методы и использовать для каких-то компонентов интерфейса?

Comment: Да вся логика по максимуму переносится во ViewModel. Вьюшка "тупая" и просто подписывается на изменения во ViewModel используя для этого    LiveData или Coroutines Flow

Comment: Спасибо стало немного понятнее.